# How to set default values for layout variables?

Tags: template-layouts, layout-variables

I'd like to set some default values for several [layout variables](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/layouts.html#layout-variables), for when a particular template doesn't have a need to pass a specific variable to the parent layout. For example, I set my page's "description" meta tag via a layout variable, but some pages don't need a unique description - they should just use a "global" description. Setting defaults would save a lot of extraneous code in each template.

I tried doing a conditional check in my layout template:

```
{if layout:description == ''}
    {layout:set name="description" value="My default site description."}
{/if}
```

But that doesn't work, because `layout:set` tags are not parsed inside layout templates.

How can I set defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is in looking at the [template engine order of operations](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html#rendering-stages). You can see that snippets are processed very early on. It also so happens that if you set a layout variable multiple times, it's the last value which remains.

So you can create a snippet which sets default for all of your metadata, then include that snippet alongside your layout tag in all your templates. Then, call `{layout:set}` for only the variables you need to change per-template.

#### Template

```
{layout="_global/_layout"}
{sn_default_metadata}

<p>Hello world.</p>
```

#### Layout file (_global/_layout)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{lang}">
<head>
    <meta charset="{charset}" />
    <meta name="description" content="{layout:description}" />
    <meta name="thumbnail" content="{layout:thumbnail}" />
    {if layout:robots}<meta name="robots" content="{layout:robots}" />{/if}

    <meta property="og:title" content="{if layout:title}{layout:title}{if:else}{layout:site_name}{/if}" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="{layout:description}" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="{layout:thumbnail}" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="{layout:url}" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="{layout:open_graph_type}" />

    <title>{if layout:title}{layout:title} &ndash; {/if}{layout:site_name}</title>
</head>
<body>

    {layout:contents}

</body>
</html>
```

#### Snippet ({sn_default_metadata})

```
{layout:set name="description" value="My default site description."}
{layout:set name="open_graph_type" value="website"}
{layout:set name="site_name" value="My Great Website"}
{layout:set name="thumbnail" value="{site_url}/assets/img/thumbnail.png"}
{layout:set name="url" value="{current_url}"}
```

### Template with overrides

```
{layout="_global/_layout"}
{sn_default_metadata}

{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="1"}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <img src="{news_image}" alt="" />
    {news_body}

    {layout:set name="title" value="{title}"}
    {layout:set name="description" value="{news_summary}"}
    {layout:set name="url" value="{title_permalink="news/entry"}"}
    {layout:set name="thumbnail" value="{news_image}"}
    {layout:set name="open_graph_type" value="article"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Since layout variables are parsed before preload_replace ones, you can use it to set the defaults.

Comment: Can you elaborate Robson? Interested in seeing other examples of how to achieve this.

Comment: Something like `{preload_replace:layout:robots="index,follow,noarchive"}
<meta name="robots" content="{layout:robots}">`

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work at all in my testing. I don't think you can `preload_replace` layout vars.

Comment: I tested this and it worked. I even talked about to EllisLab. Just drop this on the layout file and it should work.

Comment: You've put the defaults into the template, IMHO it makes more sense to have it in the layout.